How to create hexagonal pattern on a mesh?
I want to create a similar hexagonal mesh on a curved surface
Here is the reference image:

This is my 3D model:


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

May I recommend to read this : How can I create a hexagonal structure with Geometry Nodes? or that : Applying a polygonal (hexagonal) grid to a surface ?

It would probably be easier to use a normal map in this situation. Seems appropriate. Does it need to be geometry?

I tried modelling the shape but its not working, A normal map is the solution for it Thank you
